# Embedded elasticsearch is not accessible from outside

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have Spring Boot app with embedded elasticsearch. I can access it on as localhost:9200 but it doesn't respond with real IP xx.xxx.x.xx:9200.

Port is open, problem is that it is listening local interface only.

```
netstat -vanp tcp | grep 9200
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.9200         *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072  31425      0
tcp6       0      0  ::1.9200               *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072  31425      0
tcp6       0      0  fe80::1%lo0.9200       *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072  31425      0
```

How to force it listen all, like I have for web 8080

```
netstat -vanp tcp | grep 8080
tcp46      0      0  *.8080                 *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072  23002      0
```

I am using:

- spring-boot-starter-parent   1.4.1.RELEASE
- spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch  1.4.1.RELEASE
- elasticsearch version 2.4.0

and here is part of my application-dev.yml

```
data:
    elasticsearch:
        cluster-name:
        cluster-nodes:
        properties:
            path:
              logs: target/elasticsearch/log
              data: target/elasticsearch/data
            http:
              enabled: true
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind your embedded Elasticsearch to all host ips(or at least to the real ip of the machine), it looks to me that you're binding to localhost, so you need this entry while configuring your elasticsearch:

```
Settings.Builder nodeSettings = nodeBuilder().settings();
...
nodeSettings.put("network.host", "0.0.0.0");
```

this will bind your elasticsearch to also bind to your host ip address.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works fine. I have applied your approach to **application-dev.yml**   `network: host: 0.0.0.0`  - sorry comments here doesn't support new line

Comment: Yeah, sure. I did it in code because you mentioned that you're using it embedded. BTW you're probably aware but from 5.x elasticsearch does not support embedded mode anymore: https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-the-server

Comment: Thank you for the note. Will be prepared.